# Site.com pages migration from Sandbox to Production

Tags: site.com

When you build a Salesforce site.com (not force.com site) pages do you build directly in production ? In other words, can you build site.com pages and artifacts in a Sandbox and deploy them to production org through tradition Force.com IDE, change set or via ant scripts ?

Looking for best practices around the development methodology for Site.com.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the traditional model is to build Site.com sites directly in the production org. Site.com has its own "sandbox like" environment in the way that your in-development version of the site is not publically available until after you publish.

Sandbox support for Site.com is introduced in Winter'14, see the [Release Notes](https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_winter14_release_notes.pdf)